# ¿Cuál es la etimología de la palabra "ropa"?

Tags: vocabulario

[image]

> ### ¿Cuáles son los orígenes de la palabra "ropa"?

Answer (score 2):

Del gótico * (*raupa, "botín"), a su vez de  (raupjan, "saquear"), referidas a cubrimientos de tela en general, De la misma familia procede la palabra "**robar**".

https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/ropa

Comment: De la misma familia gótica, raupa, raupjan (botín, saquear).

Comment: Una familia de palabras son un conjunto de palabras que por su procedencia tienen en común una parte de la palabra. En este caso el morfema "Rau" donde "au" derivaría en "o", "Ro", es la parte de la palabra que lleva el significado referencial.